# Issue displaying customiser setting with get_theme_mod

Tags: theme-customizer

I've created two custom fields within the customiser, a text field and a dropdown-pages field. The dropdown-pages field (button_1_link) works fine but the text field (button_1_text) doesn't display any value. I've checked the db entry and there is a value stored for that field. Can anyone explain what the issue is please?

```
function header_customizer( $wp_customize )
{
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'header_buttons', array(
        'title' => __('Header Buttons', 'test_theme'),
        'priority' => 99,
        'description' => __('You can change the header buttons here') 
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'button_1_text_settings', array(
        'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'default' => __('Primary Button Text', 'test_theme'),
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'button_1_link_settings', array(
        'default' => __('Primary Button Link', 'test_theme'),
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'button_1_text', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Primary Button', 'test_theme' ),
        'section'  => 'header_buttons',
        'settings' => 'button_1_text_settings',
        'type'     => 'text'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'button_1_link', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Primary Button Link', 'test_theme' ),
        'section'  => 'header_buttons',
        'settings' => 'button_1_link_settings',
        'type'     => 'dropdown-pages'
    ));
}
```

In header.php to display:

```
$button_1 = get_theme_mod( 'button_1_text' );
$page_id_1 = get_theme_mod( 'button_1_link' );              
echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($page_id_1) . '">' . $button_1 . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `settings` attribute you're using for [`add_control()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_control/) is expecting an array of all settings tied to the control while you're passing a string. The attribute you want is the singular `setting` which is expecting the string value of the primary setting for the control.

So try this:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'button_1_text', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Primary Button', 'test_theme' ),
    'section'  => 'header_buttons',
    'setting' => 'button_1_text_settings',
    'type'     => 'text'
));
```

It's also not clear to me if it's best practice, but I tend to use the same string as my setting ID for my control ID, then I can just omit the `setting` attribute since it defaults to the ID, like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'button_1_text', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'default' => __('Primary Button Text', 'test_theme'),
    'transport' => 'postMessage'
));
$wp_customize->add_control( 'button_1_text', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Primary Button', 'test_theme' ),
    'section'  => 'header_buttons',
    'type'     => 'text'
));
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks so much for your help, that change has worked.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!